# Python recursive function enter

Tags: python, function, recursion

ps: This question was just marked as duplicate and there was already an answer. The thing is, this question is not the same as the other one. In this problem, I already know where my code was wrong. Im asking WHY it was wrong.

This is a problem on udacity that I was asked to solve:

> Define a procedure is_palindrome, that takes as input a string, and returns a
>   Boolean indicating if the input string is a palindrome.
>
> Hint:
>
> Base Case: `''` => `True`
>
> Recursive Case: if first and last characters don't match => `False`

If they do match, is the middle a palindrome?

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if s=='':
        return True
    else:
        if s[0]!=s[-1]:
            return False
        else:
            s=s[1:-1]
            is_palindrome(s)
```

And the 3 input cases to try:

```
print is_palindrome('')
#>>> True
print is_palindrome('abab')
#>>> False
print is_palindrome('abba')
#>>> True
```

If I leave my code like that, it will return None for case 'abba'. It can be fixed by changing the last line of the function into

```
return is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

May I ask why the `return` matter? Even without the return, shouldn't it just run the function `is_palindrome()` over again and again?

Answer (score 7):

> Even without the return, shouldnt it just run the function is_palindrome() over again and again?

Sure -- It'll run it over and over, but it won't *return* anything useful, so you'll never get to see the result.  This is because the first `is_palindrome` call will return `None` independent of the return values of the recursing calls to `is_palindrome` (`None` is Python's default when you don't specify a return value).

Comment: When `is_palindrome` is run again and checked again, there're already some `return` in it, but these run-again-inner `return` wont be returned?

Answer (score 1):

This task, doesn't require recursion:

```
In [2]: "aloof"[::-1]
Out[2]: 'foola'
```

Solve it simply and move on.

Comment: I know how to do it easy way. The lesson just used the problem as an example of how Recursive Functions can be useful